# How to generate a flat array of ancestors from a flat normalized array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a flat array of objects containing all ancestors of a given object in a flat normalized array of objects.

Lots of examples exist for turning it into a nested tree like structure, but I haven't been able to find any info for simply returning all ancestors in a flat array. Each object in the flat normalized array has an id and a parentId.

Given a flat normalized array of objects

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "node 1",
    parentId: null,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "node 2",
    parentId: 1,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "node 3",
    parentId: null,
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "node 4",
    parentId: 3,
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "node 5",
    parentId: 2,
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: "node 6",
    parentId: 1,
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: "node 7",
    parentId: 6,
  },
]
```

When doing `getAncestors(1)` it should return all ancestors of node 1

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "node 2",
    parentId: 1,
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "node 5",
    parentId: 2,
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: "node 6",
    parentId: 1,
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: "node 7",
    parentId: 6,
  },
]
```

I've tried modifying the functions for turning it into a nested tree like structure, but without luck.

Comment: you still need a tree, or at least a stack. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: Problem is not to generate the nested tree. That is very easy, since there are lots of examples on how to do that. And it would of course be trivial to turn that one into a flat array afterwards. I was hoping for some help doing this directly, so I do not have to build a tree first and then walk it to generate that flat array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faaster access, you need a `Map` with all nodes and their `id` as key as well as a map for all parents with `parentId` as key. Then you need the function `getAncestors` and inside, you need a function for getting a nod an it's ancestors as well.

Combine all with a reducing and return the result.

```js
function getAncestors(parentId) {
    const getNode = node => [node, ...getAncestors(node.id)];
    return (parents.get(parentId) || []).reduce((r, id) => [...r, ...getNode(nodes.get(id))], []);
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "node 1", parentId: null, }, { id: 2, name: "node 2", parentId: 1 }, { id: 3, name: "node 3", parentId: null }, { id: 4, name: "node 4", parentId: 3 }, { id: 5, name: "node 5", parentId: 2 }, { id: 6, name: "node 6", parentId: 1 }, { id: 7, name: "node 7", parentId: 6 }],
    nodes = new Map(data.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    parents = data.reduce((m, { id, parentId }) => m.set(parentId, [... (m.get(parentId) || []), id]), new Map);

console.log(getAncestors(1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow amazing. Can't believe how long time such algorithms can take for some of us to come up with. Gj. Would be even more amazing if you didn't have to make the nodes and parents map (or to them in getAncestors somehow), but this will get the job done. Gj!